# Updating a grid in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, grid

I have a grid and in the grid some images. In the image I have a tap event, which should change the image. I want to show the image before the program leaves the tap subroutine because I have some following code. My last try was:

```
private void img_Tap_43(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Karte_drehen(4, 3);
    Grid.SetRow(this.tmpimg1, 4);
    Grid.SetColumn(this.tmpimg1, 3);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        this.UpdateLayout();
    });//Ende Dispatcher
}
```

XAML Code is: `<Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Name="img43" Source="Images/Karte00.jpg" Margin="5" Tap="img_Tap_43"></Image>`
I am using Windows Phone 7.1.